# Linked list insertion doesn't work as expected

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that places new nodes alphabetically into a linked list structure by sorting them by the name field. Here is my program, intended to test that it can successfully insert a new node into an existing structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_JOB_LENGTH 100

struct Employee
{
    /* Employee details */
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1]; /* name string */
    char sex; /* sex identifier, either ’M’ or ’F’ */
    int age; /* age */
    char job[MAX_JOB_LENGTH+1]; /* job string */
    /* pointers to previous and next employee structures in the linked list
     (for if you use a linked list instead of an array) */
    struct Employee *prev, *next;
};

void place_alpha(struct Employee *new, struct Employee **root);

int main(){
    struct Employee *a;
    struct Employee *c;
    struct Employee *b;
    a = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    c = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));
    b = malloc(sizeof(struct Employee));

    strcpy(a->name, "A");
    a->sex = 'F';
    a->age = 42;
    strcpy(a->job, "Optician");
    a->prev = NULL;
    a->next = c;

    strcpy(c->name, "C");
    c->sex = 'F';
    c->age = 22;
    strcpy(c->job, "Nurse");
    c->prev = a;
    c->next = NULL;

    strcpy(b->name, "B");
    b->sex = 'M';
    b->age = 34;
    strcpy(b->job, "Rockstar");
    b->prev = NULL;
    b->next = NULL;

    place_alpha(b, &a);

    if(a->prev == NULL)
    {
        printf("a->prev is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("a->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }

    if(a->next == b)
    {
        printf("a->next is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("a->next is INCORRECT");
    }

    if(b->prev == a)
    {
        printf("b->prev is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("b->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }

    if(b->next == c)
    {
        printf("b->next is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("b->next is INCORRECT\n");
    }

    if(c->prev == b)
    {
        printf("c->prev is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("c->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }

    if(c->next == NULL)
    {
        printf("c->next is correct\n");
    }else{
        printf("c->next is INCORRECT\n");
    }
}

void place_alpha(struct Employee *new, struct Employee **root) //Places a new node new into the database structure whose root is root.
{
    if(*root==NULL) //If there is no database yet.
    {
        *root = new;
        (*root)->prev = NULL;
        (*root)->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(new->name, (*root)->name)<=0) // if the new node comes before root alphabetically
        {
            new->next = *root;
            new->prev = (*root)->prev;
            if((*root)->prev != NULL)
            {
                (*root)->prev->next = new;
            }
            (*root)->prev = new;

            *root = new;
            return;
        }
        else if((*root)->next == NULL) // If the next node is NULL (we've reached the end of the database so new has to go here.
        {
            new->prev = *root;
            new->next = NULL;
            (*root)->next = new;
            return;
        }
        else if(strcmp(new->name, (*root)->name)>0) // If the new node comes after root alphabetically
        {
            place_alpha(new, &(*root)->next);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, the program is unsuccessful, as showcased by the output:

```
a->prev is correct
a->next is correct
b->prev is INCORRECT
b->next is correct
c->prev is INCORRECT
c->next is correct
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I can't figure out why, as I've clearly set `b->next` to `c` and `c->prev` to `b`.

Comment: Dont use `new` as a name of variable. In C, it is OK, but it is a bad habbit if you move to C++

Comment: You are placing b before a... inside strcmp!

Comment: Your strcmp has wrong paranthesis. <=0 should be outside

Comment: M.Alnashmi, `strcmp(new_node->name, (*root)->name)<=0` looks correct to me...

Comment: @Martin Perry: C and C++ are different languages. There's nothing wrong with using `new` as a variable name in C. If we start thinking along the lines of "what if I move to a different language", we'll lose too many good variable names.

Comment: @AnT: of course it is not *wrong*, it is just inelegant. It makes the code harder to port to C++, it fools the colorizer, as can be seen above, it may confuse the reader... But it is a good way to make sure the compiler is in C mode ;-)

Comment: @chqrlie: The matter of "porting the code C++" is a rather niche one and should not affect variable naming decisions. Even if one decides to do the porting, such variable names will be the least of their worries. "Fools the colorizer" is the problem of the colorizer (file a bug report or feature request). "Confuse the reader" is the problem of the reader (reader should learn to switch between these two different languages).

Comment: @AnT: Not everyone is as self confident as you are. Choosing to disallow c++ keywords as identifiers is indeed mostly a question of local practice and code conventions. I side with Martin Perry: it is OK, but probably a bad habit.

Comment: @chqrlie: I just don't see where the "habit" comes into the picture here. Whatever decision process the author of the code uses when choosing variable names, it just produces when they consider "the best" variable name for the given context. Just because the name happened to coincide with a C++ keyword does not in any way imply that the author has a "habit" of using C++ keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was tricky: there is a subtile bug in your `place_alpha()` function: you update `*root` even if it is not the root node of the list.  This causes the pointer `b` to be updated erroneously. `place_alpha()` should only be called with a pointer to the actual root node.

I modified your code to make it more readable and reliable:

- I wrote a function to create a new node
- I protected the string copies from overflow using `calloc()` and `strncat()`. Read about these functions in the manual.
- I use `place_alpha()` to insert all 3 nodes into the `list` in the same order you do.
- I use `newp` instead of `new` to avoid C++ keywords in C code.

Note that `place_alpha()` must be called with a pointer to the head pointer of the list, if you pass a pointer to an intermediary node, chaining back along the `prev` links would locate the first node, but if the new employee should be inserted at the head of the list, you would not have the address of the root node to update in the caller's scope.  This is the reason many programmers prefer to use a specific structure for the list head.

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_JOB_LENGTH  100

struct Employee {
    /* Employee details */
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 1]; /* name string */
    char sex; /* sex identifier, either 'M' or 'F' */
    int age; /* age */
    char job[MAX_JOB_LENGTH + 1]; /* job string */
    /* pointers to previous and next employee structures in the linked list
       (for if you use a linked list instead of an array) */
    struct Employee *prev, *next;
};

void place_alpha(struct Employee *new, struct Employee **root);

struct Employee *new_employee(const char *name, char sex, int age, const char *job) {
    struct Employee *newp = calloc(1, sizeof(*newp));
    if (!newp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate employee\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    strncat(newp->name, name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
    newp->sex = sex;
    newp->age = age;
    strncat(newp->job, job, MAX_JOB_LENGTH);
    newp->next = newp->prev = NULL;
    return newp;
}

int main(void) {
    struct Employee *list = NULL;
    struct Employee *a = new_employee("A", 'F', 42, "Optician");
    struct Employee *b = new_employee("B", 'M', 34, "Rockstar");
    struct Employee *c = new_employee("C", 'F', 22, "Nurse");

    place_alpha(a, &list);
    place_alpha(c, &list);
    place_alpha(b, &list);

    if (a->prev == NULL) {
        printf("a->prev is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("a->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }
    if (a->next == b) {
        printf("a->next is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("a->next is INCORRECT");
    }
    if (b->prev == a) {
        printf("b->prev is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("b->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }
    if (b->next == c) {
        printf("b->next is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("b->next is INCORRECT\n");
    }
    if (c->prev == b) {
        printf("c->prev is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("c->prev is INCORRECT\n");
    }
    if (c->next == NULL) {
        printf("c->next is correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("c->next is INCORRECT\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

void place_alpha(struct Employee *newp, struct Employee **root) {
    // Insert a new node newp into the database structure whose root is root.
    struct Employee *ep;

    if (*root == NULL) { // if there is no database yet.
        newp->next = newp->prev = NULL;
        *root = newp;
        return;
    }
    if ((*root)->prev) {
        // invalid call, should only pass the root node address
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid call: place_alpha must take a pointer to the root node\n");
        return;
    }
    if (strcmp(newp->name, (*root)->name) <= 0) {
        // if the new node comes before root alphabetically
        newp->next = *root;
        newp->prev = NULL;
        newp->next->prev = newp;
        *root = newp;
        return;
    }
    for (ep = *root;; ep = ep->next) {
        if (ep->next == NULL) {
            // If the next node is NULL, we've reached the end of the list
            // so newp has to go here.
            newp->prev = ep;
            newp->next = NULL;
            newp->prev->next = newp;
            return;
        }
        if (strcmp(newp->name, ep->next->name) <= 0) {
            // The new node comes between ep and ep->next alphabetically
            newp->prev = ep;
            newp->next = ep->next;
            newp->prev->next = newp->next->prev = newp;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** `place_alpha` was a bit redundant, so I cleaned it and got a much simpler version:

```
void place_alpha(struct Employee *newp, struct Employee **root) {
    //Places a new node newp into the database structure whose root is root.
    struct Employee **link = root;
    struct Employee *last = NULL;

    while (*link && strcmp(newp->name, (*link)->name) > 0) {
        last = *link;
        link = &last->next;
    }
    newp->prev = last;
    newp->next = *link;
    if (newp->next) {
        newp->next->prev = newp;
    }
    *link = newp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does this mean one cannot do the placing of a new node recursively in this case?

Comment: Using recursion for this is not a good idea and is not needed.  It makes the code more complicated, and if the compiler does not optimize the tail recursion, you may recurse many times for a long list, potentially causing a **stack overflow**

Comment: Okay. Another question, your comment `//The new node comes between newp and newp->next alphabetically`, should be `//The new node comes between ep and ep->next alphabetically`, right? Because newp isn't even in the list yet. Just making sure I understand you correctly

Comment: Alright! Also, could 
`newp->prev = ep;
newp->next = ep->next;
newp->prev->next = newp->next->prev = newp;`

 be changed to:
         
`newp->prev = ep;
newp->next = ep->next;
ep->next = ep->prev = newp;
return;` ?

Makes more sense to me.

Comment: This is in the last `if`-statement in `place_alpha()`

Comment: @Sandi: no, your proposed replacement is flawed: the last assignment should be `ep->next = ep->next->prev = newp;` but I like the symmetry in my version better.  The compiler is probably good enough to generate equivalent code for both.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. My mistake. Good to know that they both work. Thanks!

Comment: @Sandi: doubly linked lists are tricky, and so are circular lists.  You seem to have a good understanding of pointer techniques, hone this skill, it is a life saver in C.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `place_alpha` was a bit redundant, so I cleaned it and got a much simpler version.  Can you confirm it works correctly?